# Trying to get slick working on a simple play2 app

Tags: playframework-2.0, slick

I'm using IntelliJ 13, my build.sbt looks like:

```
name := "hello"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  //"org.apache.tomcat" %% "tomcat-jdbc" % "8.0.5",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.30",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "2.0.1"
)

play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

My model is giving compilation errors:

```
package models

import java.sql.Date
import scala.slick.model.Table
import scala.slick.lifted.Tag
import scala.slick.direct.AnnotationMapper.column
import scala.slick.driver.JdbcProfile
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver._

//class Actions(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, String, Int, Int, Int, Int, Date, Date)](tag, "actions") {
class Actions(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, Date, Date)](tag, "actions") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def description = column[String]("description")

  def createdAt = column[Date]("created_at")
  def updatedAt = column[Date]("updated_at")

  def * = (id, name, description, createdAt, updatedAt)
}
```

The compile errors are:

```
 Error:(10, 33) scala.slick.model.Table does not take type parameters
    class Actions(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, Date, Date)](tag, "actions") {
                                    ^
    Error:(10, 14) too many arguments for constructor Object: ()Object
    class Actions(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String, Date, Date)](tag, "actions") {
                 ^
    Error:(11, 18) object column does not take type parameters.
      def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
                     ^
    Error:(12, 20) object column does not take type parameters.
      def name = column[String]("name")
                       ^
    Error:(13, 27) object column does not take type parameters.
      def description = column[String]("description")
                              ^
    Error:(15, 25) object column does not take type parameters.
      def createdAt = column[Date]("created_at")
                            ^
    Error:(16, 25) object column does not take type parameters.
      def updatedAt = column[Date]("updated_at")

                        ^
```

I first wanted to use tomcat jdbc but I think that requires me to create some fancy jdbcwrapper so I just commented that out for now as I just want to get a simple connection working.

My db connection looks like:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/play-test"
db.default.user=root
db.default.pass=""
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace **all** of your slick imports with only this one import:

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
```

Then you'll have `Table`, `Tag`, etc. all in scope.

Slick's samples might help: https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/FirstExample.scala

And the documentation: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/gettingstarted.html#quick-introduction

Comment: Updated for Slick 3:
`import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._`